# How to vent large outdoor undercover area

Tags: vent, exhaust-fan

I have a large (95 sq meters) undercover area behind my house:

[image: entertainment area]

A few things to note:

1. The house is just to the left of the picture.
2. The roof of this area slants from the house to the far wall (as you would expect)
3. There is a barbecue just outside the photo to the right
4. Even further to the right, fairly close to the bbq, is a clothesline for hanging clothes

When I am cooking on the barbecue, the area can get quite smoky, as you would expect. The smoke even gets in the house quite a lot if I leave the doors open. I'm thinking of installing a vent in the roof, but I am not sure where or what kind of vent to get.

### Location of the vent

There are three options that I see.

1. Directly above the bbq, the most obvious option
2. In the middle of the area (both axes)
3. Against the house, but in the middle on the other axis

What if I want to move the bbq one day? If I put the vent right above the bbq, then it will be at the lowest point in the roof, so I feel like I will get smoke trapped against the house as it rises due to the slant in the roof. Are there any other gases besides bbq smoke that I might want to extract? This area is not currently accessible with a vehicle but I would like to make it accessible one day. I am a brand new homeowner so haven't any experience in this regard.

### Type of vent

A few options here...

1. Turbine vent
2. Powered exhaust fan with an actual switch
3. Regular house fan that I can move around and isn't installed in the roof

Do I want to be able to turn it on and off? A turbine vent is not powered, correct? So it is always on? Or at least when there is wind blowing. Maybe this isn't necessary and I only need a regular fan to keep the air moving?

Thanks!

Comment: There would have to be a powered vent hood over the barbecue exhausting out the roof to eliminate the smoke. Otherwise you must move the bbq out from under the roof, and even then if the direction of the wind is wrong the smoke will be carried under the roof. Soot and fat will adhere to the underside of the roof and be a cleaning nightmare.

Comment: What is your climate like?

Comment: I'd move either the BBQ or clothesline to be as far apart as possible; preferably with the BBQ as close to the lowest eave as possible, so that smoke had the farthest to travel before reaching the house but the shortest to travel (upward) to rise above the roof.  I would think, then, a simple pole-fan would fare well to draw smoke away from the house.

Comment: The climate is very mild. Most of the year between 5 and 15 C, rarely colder than 0 C, rarely hotter than 30 C